# Как расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Лучшим способом узнать достоверную информацию о китайской розе будет заглянуть в учебник по ботанике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Некорректный вариант**: Лучшим способом узнать достоверную информацию о китайской розе **будет заглянуть** в учебник по ботанике.

Структура предложения неверна. Здесь или используется неоправданная инверсия членов предложения, или неправильно составлено сказуемое "будет заглянуть".

2) Правильно:  **Заглянуть** в учебник по ботанике **будет лучшим способом** узнать достоверную информацию о китайской розе.

Подлежащее: заглянуть, сказуемое: будет лучшим способом.

3) **Сочетание "будет/было заглянуть" не является составным сказуемым,** так как глагол БЫТЬ может быть связкой только в составном именном сказуемом.

В то же время  связка было/будет используется в качестве дополнительной, если в составном глагольном сказуемом уже есть связка, выраженная модальным наречием, например: **Нужно было** сразу **пойти** к нему и всё рассказать.

4) Но лучше выглядит уже предложенный вариант: **Лучший способ узнать достоверную информацию о китайской розе - это заглянуть в учебник по ботанике.**

Answer (score 3):

"Лучшим способом узнать ... будет заглянуть" - конструкция требует правки, не оставляйте предложение в таком виде.

***Лучший способ узнать достоверную информацию о китайской розе - заглянуть в учебник по ботанике.***

Comment: Согласен, коряво, но можно ли сказать, что неправильно? А что скажете, если поставить "будет" в прошедшем времени (было) или в сослагательном наклонении (было бы)?

Comment: Ну и в прошедшем времени понадобился бы глагол "(лучшим способом) было". Тире нужно только в настоящем времени (в случае актуальности способа при имеющемся контексте), оно заменяет глагол "(лучший способ) есть".

Comment: @Alex_ander, в вопросе стоит буд, вр. (будет). Если по смыслу имеется в виду наст. вр. - вариант Екатерины **лучше**, однако я спросил можно ли сказать, что "будет" - **неправильно**

Comment: Можно придумать контекст, в котором "будет" обозначает именно буд. время. Например: Когда мы вернемся из нашего путешествия, лучшим способом узнать достоверную информацию о китайской розе будет заглянуть в учебник по ботанике. Как прикажете править такое предложение?

Comment: Я о том, что и исходное предложение не нужно править, оно возможно в соотв. контексте, который не обязан входить в само предложение.

Answer (score 1):

1. Корректно: "лучш**и**м способом".
2. По-моему, требуется только один знак препинания - точка в конце предложения.